# What are the best practices in R for writing logical controls in to your code?

Tags: r, logical-operators

I'm looking for ideas on how to code controls in to my R code. I'm writing a data model that uses many different data sources. Sources will be updated periodically. I'm afraid that there might be some changes do the data that might still work with the code I have written but give wrong results. To somewhat help me protect against it i want to write in to code parts that do some simple logical checks in the middle of the process.

For example: If number of lines in DF1 < then in DF2; There are no NA's in column X in DF3 etc etc.

I was wondering how to write code in the manner that if the logical test is FALSE then it stops the process and does not run any more code (gives me an error) even if it still could run it to the end.

Are there any other ideas you can suggest to me or refer some literature I should study to help me overcome my plight.

Thank you,

Comment: See `help("stopifnot")`. Of course, your code should be wrapped in a function, so execution stops when an error is signalled.

Comment: Check the assertive packages. Or assertr.

Comment: `if (this_should_be_lower > this_should_be_higher) stop("The lower thing was bigger than the higher thing")`